# How to find the location(s) of specific characters in a string

Tags: string, bash

With the aid of this [question](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZ__3otrzKAhVDLpQKHWYqAJAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F229551%2Fstring-contains-in-bash&usg=AFQjCNHnUWaMmF7_-6FrSFjAzwHosCaD8g&sig2=P01I7ei_nIPnZs58Cl37gQ), I can find out if a string holds a specific character. I want to be able to find out where the character actually is. For example for the string `banana`, how would I be able to determine the letter `n` is the 3rd and 5th letter, or for the letter `a` is the 2nd,4th and 6th letter. and `b` is the first letter.

**Q:** For a given string, how can I find the location of a given character in that string?

Comment: I can't think of any easier way other than a loop that tests each character.

Comment: Check out this link :http://superuser.com/questions/434507/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-bash. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `for` loop.

```
char=a
string=banana
len=${#string}
for (( i=0; i < len; i++ )); do
    if [[ $char == ${string:$i:1} ]]
    then echo $i
    fi
done
```

The positions printed are zero-based. You could echo `$((i+1))` to get 1-based positions instead.

`${string:$i:1}` extracts the `i`th character of the string, using bash's substring operator, as explained in [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>   This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to `length` characters of the value of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`.

Comment: Any chance explaining what `${string:$i:1}` does

Comment: I've added the explanation, including the documentation you could have read yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancy way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

findChar(){
    string="${1}"
    char="${2}"

    length=${#string}
    offset=0

    r=()

    while true; do
        string="${string#*${char}}"
        length_new="${#string}"
        if [[ "${length}" == "${length_new}" ]]; then
            echo "${r[@]}"
            return
        fi
        offset=($(( $offset + $length - $length_new )))
        r+=("${offset}")
        length="${length_new}"
    done
}

findChar banana b
findChar banana a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} < 4 ]] && { echo "Requires bash 4."; exit 1; }

string="${1:-banana}"

declare -A result=()

for ((i=0; i<${#string}; i++)); do
    result[${string:$i:1}]="${result[${string:$i:1}]} $i"
done

declare -p result
```

The idea is that we walk through the string, adding character positions to strings that are values in an array whose subscripts are the letters you're interested in. It's quick & easy, and gives you a result set you can manipulate afterwards, rather than just sending things to stdout.

My result with this is:

```
$ ./foo
declare -A result='([a]=" 1 3 5" [b]=" 0" [n]=" 2 4" )'
$ ./foo barber
declare -A result='([a]=" 1" [b]=" 0 3" [e]=" 4" [r]=" 2 5" )'
```

Results are zero-based (i.e. "b" is in position 0).

Note an interesting side-effect of this method is that every position is preceded by a space, so if you want to count the number of occurrences of a character, you can just count the spaces:

```
$ declare -A result
$ result[a]=" 1 3 5"
$ count="${result[a]//[0-9]/}"
$ echo "${#count}"
3
$
```

I don't know what you're planning to do with this data, but if you like, you could easily turn these string results into arrays of their own for easier handling within bash.

Note that associative arrays were introduced with bash version 4.